# lebesgue measurable limit

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I came across the following problem which I would like to solve.

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a lebesgue integrable function. Prove the following:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x+n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x-n)=0$$

Would like to solve this myself (partially) and would appreciate (only) hints

Thanks

Comment: You mean lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @Shashi Sry, messed this up :P

Comment: The proof I have seen  starts with rewriting the integral as a series and integral. And after that they conclude that convergence of the series implies that $f(x+n) $ goes to zero. Try that. I think more than this will be too much for a hint.

Comment: @Shashi Thans. I dont need more than this. Appreciate your answer. You could have made an actual answer instead of commentating, so I can give you credits :P

Comment: But a function like the indicator function of $\mathbb Q$ is lebesgue integral isn't it? If so the for a fixed $x$ the limits do not even exist. Am I misinterpreting your question?

Answer (score 0):

Integrability is not enough. Consider $$\varphi(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty k \, \chi_{[k - 2^{-k}, \, k + 2^{-k}]}(x),$$

where $$ \chi_A (x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if} \; x \in A , \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}; \end{cases}$$

Then $$
\int \varphi(x) \, d\mu(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} k \mu[k-2^{-k}, \, k + 2^{-k}] = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty 2k 2^{-k} < \infty,
$$

so $\varphi$ is integrable. But $$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty, \, k \in \mathbb{N}} \varphi(k) = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty, \, k \in \mathbb{N}} k = \infty.$$